# Getting object Object in request & parameters

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-6

Observing following in rails server logs:

```
Started GET "/jwt_api/navbar_stats?brand_id=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&user_id=%5Bobject%20Object%5D" for ::1 at 2022-11-29 12:24:04 +0530
Processing by JwtApi::NavbarStatsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"brand_id"=>"[object Object]", "user_id"=>"[object Object]"}
```

Request raised from React side:

```
import { isEqual, get } from 'lodash'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

export const REQUEST_NAVBAR_STATS = 'REQUEST_NAVBAR_STATS';
export const RECEIVE_NAVBAR_STATS = 'RECEIVE_NAVBAR_STATS';

const requestNavbarStats = () => ({ type: REQUEST_NAVBAR_STATS });
const receiveNavbarStats = (data) => ({ type: RECEIVE_NAVBAR_STATS, data });

export const fetchNavbarStats = () => (dispatch) => {
  console.log("bId", Cookies.get('bId'));
  console.log("uId", Cookies.get('uId'));
  dispatch(requestNavbarStats());
  $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/jwt_api/navbar_stats`,
    data: { brand_id: Cookies.get('bId'), user_id: Cookies.get('uId') },
    success(data) {
      dispatch(receiveNavbarStats(data));
    },
    error(xhr) {
      console.log(xhr)
      // dispatch(receiveServerErrors(xhr));
    },
  });
};
```

Rails NavbarStatsController#show code is as follows:

```
class JwtApi::NavbarStatsController < JwtApiController
  def show
    render json: {
      counts: counts,
      current_user: current_user,
      brands: brands,
      currentBrand: current_brand,
      brandPicture: current_brand.try(:picture),
      roles: current_user.roles.pluck(:name),
      priority_notification: {
        new_videos_count: new_videos,
        trending_videos_count: t_videos,
      } 
    }
  end
end
```

Expecting to get brand_id & user_id in request & parameters as follows:

```
Started GET "/jwt_api/navbar_stats?brand_id=62181bf113d9c187cb00004c&user_id=58bd3736acce3487e7000001" for ::ffff:103.179.39.185 at 2022-11-29 07:08:58 +0000
Processing by JwtApi::NavbarStatsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"brand_id"=>"62181bf113d9c187cb00004c", "user_id"=>"58bd3736acce3487e7000001"}
```

Using MongoDB as database.

Comment: Have you tried any basic debugging like for example using `console.log(bId)` in your fetchNavbarStats function? It may not be what you expect it to be and certainly isn't serializing properly.

Comment: Yes @max as suggested tried debugging by adding ```console.log(bId)``` & even that is returning ```[object Object]```

Comment: We have no idea what `bId` or `uId` are since their definition is not shown in the content of this post. Please update accordingly so that we can further assist.

Comment: @engineersmnky I have updated the content of the post as suggested. Could you kindly have a look at it.

Comment: Could it be that you're saving garbage into the cookies? `[object Object]` is the default output of calling `toString()` on an object in JavaScript. For example `({foo: 'bar'}).toString() === '[object Object]'`